# Can't Change Height of UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I've been searching all over on how to change the height of the text field inside of a UISearchBar. This is my current code, which does not do what I want. I'm wondering what I need to change to get the desired results.

**Search bar initialization**

```
private var searchBar: UISearchBar = {
let search = UISearchBar()
search.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
search.searchBarStyle = .default
search.barTintColor = .none
search.placeholder = "Search project"
return search
}()
```

**Search bar constraints** (called in `viewDidLoad()`)

```
searchBar.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
searchBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 42).isActive = true
searchBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 265).isActive = true
```

**Search bar style** (called in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`)

```
super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
self.searchBar.layoutIfNeeded()
self.searchBar.layoutSubviews()

let searchTextField: UITextField? = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
var currentTextFieldBounds = searchTextField?.bounds
currentTextFieldBounds?.size.height = 130
searchTextField?.bounds = currentTextFieldBounds ?? CGRect.zero

searchBar.layoutIfNeeded()
searchBar.layoutSubviews()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to increase the height of UISearchBar by adding a background image, to resize the entire search bar frame, and then managed to resize textField by changing the font size.

First change the search bar height constraint:

```
searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 130).isActive = true
```

Create the function that will programatically create a background image for the search bar:

```
func getImageWithCustomColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

Then change font size on viewDidLayoutSubviews:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.searchBar.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.searchBar.layoutSubviews()
    
    
    self.searchBar.searchTextField.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 60.0)
    //Your custom text size
    
    searchBar.layoutIfNeeded()
    searchBar.layoutSubviews()
}
```

Finally, in viewDidLoad create an image of the same size as the desired textField custom size (your case, 130) and call the function to place the background image of the desired color on the search Bar (this case, a clear background):

```
let backgroundImage = getImageWithCustomColor(color: UIColor.clear, size: CGSize(width: 265, height: 130))

searchBar.setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, for: .normal)
```

This is the output

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works, thanks! Kind of frustrating how this is required to simply resize the height of the UISearchBar though. Am curious if there is a better, more succinct way. This will do for now though, so thanks again!

Comment: Yeah it is kind of frustrating to see how much effort and workaround takes to simply change the height of a search bar. Hope there is a better solution in the future. Happy coding!